# Volume of a "rectangular balls" sequence in nilpotent groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, haar-measure

Let $N$ be a nilpotent group (I'm interested in real linear Lie groups primarily), I'm secretly thinking of $N$ being embedded inside some $G$ such that $N$ is horospherical subgroup (meaning there exists some $a$ for which $a^{-n}Na^{n} \to e$ as $n\to\infty$).

Given such $a$ (which we may assume have a semisimple action on Lie(N)), I define the following sets
$B^{N}_{n}=\exp(a_{\log n}B_{1}a_{-\log n})$, where $B_{1} \subset Lie(N)$ is the logarithm of the Riemannian (say left-invariant) metric ball in $N$.
What is the volume of $B^{N}_{n}$?

Obviously it has to do with the normalization of the one-param group $a_{\star}$ so imagine that the sum of eigenvalues of $a_{1}$ on $Lie(N)$ equals to $1$.
Notice also that when $N$ is a nice nilpotent group (say Heisenberg) then those "rectangular balls" equals to the balls according to the CC metric.

Notice that it is well known that metric balls $B_{N}$ has exact polynomial growth with the exponent given by the Bass-Guivarch formula.

Edit - it would be helpful for me even just to get a precise power growth for this sequence.

Comment: I'm confused by your wording... first your question is about $B_N$, regardless of $a$, and you answer your own question (Bass-Guivarch). Then what do you want to do with $a$?

Comment: @YCor ,thanks for your comment Prof. Cornulier. I had a mistake, I wanted to know the volume of $B^{N}_{n}$. 
By consulting with Knapp's Lie group beyond an introduction, Ch. VIII Equation 8.38 it seems that the answer is given by the sum of the eigenvalues, is that correct? (do to the fact the measure is right-invariant and the modular function is given by the determinant of the Adjoint).